# HTML5 audio in Flowplayer

Tags: html, audio, flowplayer

I'm trying to use Flowplayer as audio-only player. But I need it to work on HTML5 only, **no Flash**.

I tried smth like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="flowplayer_video is-audio" data-engine="audio" data-embed="false"><video><source type="video/mp3" src="/test.mp3"></video></div>
```

I also tried combinations like audio tag or type="audio/mpeg" or type="audio/mp3"

JS:

```
$(".flowplayer_video").flowplayer();
```

**This throws JS errors.**

Everywhere I serach in internet it redirects me to http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/audio.html - which is Flash solution, I believe.

So, is it even possible to use Flowplayer as audio-player **without Flash**?

If no, can you advise me HTML5 player, which will be able to play video and audio-only?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 version of flowplayer does not nativly support audio only.

But: A few hours ago this plugin was released on GitHub under MIT license https://github.com/danrossi/audio-engine. It provides an audio engine for the HTML5 Flowplayer version. (I have not tried or looked into it, yet.)

It seems to be a small extraction of a larger and commercial plugin build by the same guy. http://flowplayer.electroteque.org/audio/fp5